# What values to give the variables patty and thelma so they print out "gone", but not "forgotten"

Tags: javascript

```
var patty;
var thelma;

if(patty == thelma)
  console.log("gone");
if(patty === thelma)
  console.log("forgotten");
```

I've already tried using && and || operands, and to check whether both are a string using typeof for the ===. Any ideas?

Comment: that title... have you considered using something descriptive instead?

Comment: As posted both the variables are of data type undefined, pass both tests and result in two logs to the console.  On the other hand  `0 == false` is true but `0===false` is false but I assume you know that. Could you explain more about what you are asking please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For exampel these:

```
var patty = 10;
var thelma = "10";
```